# Kendo UI: jQuery plugin vs data attribute initialization

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm just starting out with Kendo UI and would like to better understand pros/cons of *jquery initialization* vs. *data attribute initialization* for large web applications.  I'm seeing more examples using jquery, but I like the attribute approach; it feels a little like Angularjs.  At this point, my preference is very subjective and would like objective feedback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read [this post](http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/declarative_initialization) on MVVM and declarative initialization.  I think a lot of people would agree that as your app gets larger, DI becomes more and more attractive.  It's especially applicable if you are using MVVM, but you don't have to be to reap the benefits.